# How to scan for live hosts: Nmap shows all IPs only when run as root when only 4 IPs are online and incomplete results when run as “--unprivileged.”

Tags: linux, networking, debian, kali-linux, nmap

I have an issue with Nmap. I have Kali on my vm installed.

I want to scan the network for live hosts. But when I’m logged as root try `nmap -sP 192.168.0.*` Nmap reports that every IP in the subnet `192.168.0.*` was live. But actually, only 4 IPs are online.

Meanwhile, ping command return correct results; I can ping all and it only shows live hosts.

When I run `nmap -sP --unprivileged 192.168.0.*` Looks like it works, but it doesn’t return not all live hosts.

Why command n Nmap ap doesn’t work without --unprivileged flag? How can I run it correctly?

Comment: there is an "strace -t -e trace=network nmap -sP 192.168.0.218" command example (there is no host on this ip, but nmap shows it "up") https://pastebin.com/qHzsgiVi

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info): When the dust settles on this, what do you wish to have as your results? What is your end goal?

Comment: I wanted to scan network for live hosts, I tried it in a few networks, same result.  nmap -sP 192.168.0.* returns that all hosts are "up", running nmap with --unprivilege flag (but i'm logged as root) returns not all list of hosts, and --unprivilege flag limits nmap functions.

Comment: What version of Kali. I have a Kali V2019-4 VM here and the two commands you post in the first post give me the same answer. All the IPs are good except I am not sure about the .255 IP. The others are all identifiable.

Comment: Same version Kali, fully updated. Doing some google search, i found a few answers: "This is because when vmWare receive the packet, recreate it and TTL value is reinitilized and this generate confusion on Nmap scan" So, probably, the solution - is to configure vm as bridge, not NAT. But it is still strange. Is there really no way to keep "NAT" as vmware setting and do netscan? (i need NAT for some other reasons).

Comment: My connection is NAT and it works as I noted above.

Comment: Perhaps make sure that your network settings (Advanced Network Configuration in Settings) have been set to default. I have Link Negotiation set to Ignore (which is default so far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

I still can't comment so I write you here so I hope I understood you right.

> "How to scan for live hosts:"

is your question and I tested it for you on a normal linux computer and you see that at the first nmap listing it just shows what is stored from the last session. I than pinged the missing device and boom - it was shown at the second run.

```
 [jack@jacks ~]$ sudo nmap -sP --unprivileged 192.168.178.*
    Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-12-18 01:30 CET
    Nmap scan report for fritz.box (192.168.178.1)
    Host is up (0.0013s latency).
    Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.2
    Host is up (0.0014s latency).
    Nmap scan report for openwrtwan.lan (192.168.178.17)
    Host is up (0.0081s latency).
    Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.40
    Host is up (0.024s latency).
    Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 2.91 seconds
    [jack@jacks ~]$ sudo nmap -sP --unprivileged 192.168.178.*
    Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-12-18 01:31 CET
    Nmap scan report for fritz.box (192.168.178.1)
    Host is up (0.0014s latency).
    Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.2
    Host is up (0.0012s latency).
    Nmap scan report for lizzy (192.168.178.10)
    Host is up (0.057s latency).
    Nmap scan report for openwrtwan.lan (192.168.178.17)
    Host is up (0.00081s latency).
    Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.40
    Host is up (0.10s latency).
    Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 34.92 seconds
    [jack@jacks ~]$
```

A brief from Nmap website:

> `-sn (No port scan)`
>
> This option tells Nmap not to do a port scan after host discovery, and only print out the available hosts that responded to the host
> discovery probes. This is often known as a “ping scan”, but you can
> also request that traceroute and NSE host scripts be run. This is by
> default one step more intrusive than the list scan, and can often be
> used for the same purposes. It allows light reconnaissance of a target
> network without attracting much attention. Knowing how many hosts are
> up is more valuable to attackers than the list provided by list scan
> of every single IP and host name.

---

> Why command n Nmap ap doesn’t work without --unprivileged flag?

It normally has similar results if either isn't actively blocked by the firewall and you experience a difference because you pinged between the runs.

> How can I run it correctly?

Thats how: nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24 and if you're sure about some target, you can use -sP